# How to stop mapbox-gl.js tracking my mobile compass

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

When I use my mapbox-gl.js map on my mobile phone it keeps rotating as I turn my mobile phone to keep the north. How can I stop this? I do want to continue being able to rotate the map with touch gestures...

Here is the [api](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/).

Comment: You're saying that the map rotates every time the phone rotates? That sounds weird, certainly not the expected behaviour, and not something I have seen.

Can you post the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahum..., sorry, bearing tracking is not in mapbox-gl.js api at this moment. It was 'my own' code. A snippet I adjusted from somewhere and forgot about...:

```
  const easing = t => t * (2 - t)

  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', event => {
      let compassdir
      if (event.webkitCompassHeading) {
        // Apple works only with this, alpha doesn't work
        compassdir = event.webkitCompassHeading
      }
      else {
        compassdir = event.alpha
      }
      myMap.easeTo({
        bearing: 360 - compassdir,
        easing: easing
      })
    })
  }
  else {
    alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support Device Orientation")
  }
```

Comment: Fyi this is actually built-in Mapbox GL, using the `setMyBearingTrackingMode` function with the `COMPASS` value.